# Instantaneous Peak Current Delivered by a Battery

Tags: batteries, current

I am working on a project involving battery drills and would like to know the peak current an 18v 3A/Hr (54 W/Hr) battery could deliver, even if for an instant.

I can't find detailed battery datasheets, other than the [generic](http://www.makitauk.com/accessories/front/?id=1339&model=194204-5) info and one on the [chemical](http://www.manualshelf.com/manual/makita/bl1830-10/msds-english.html) composition of the battery.

The peak current would be caused not by a short circuit, but when the motor is stationary (and is generating stall torque), so there would be a completed circuit of a few milli-ohms.

Is it as simple as Voltage / (Winding Resistance + Internal Battery Resistance)?

What ballpark figures could I expect?  <50A, 100 - 150A, 150 - 200A, >200A... etc?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Instantaneous** maximum possible peak current isn't a common datasheet specification for a battery. So you are asking if, by some tremendous luck, someone has spent time characterizing the exact battery you have in hand under those circumstances and would be willing to share?

Comment: An upper bound would be V/R where R is the motor's winding resistance + battery internal R. Measure he winding R as accurately as you can or find a datasheet for the motor.

Comment: If the cells are rated 10C (pessimistic), the maximum continous discharge rate is 30A. If they are 15C cells, 45A. If they are 20C cells (optimistic), 60A. Add 50% for a 2s burst. This is all speculation, as makita doesn't publish any details, I don't know what cells are used in your battery and even if I knew the cell manufacturers don't usually publish datasheets online. If you search for "bl1830 disassembly" you will find more speculation from other people...